# How to fetch from backend database to display on frontend using react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to fetch from my backend database (MongoDB) on my localhost to display all blogposts.

I'm assuming I need to iterate through each blogpost on the frontend. Right now, only "Author" and "Comments" display, but with no actual data.

What would that syntax look like?

Here's what the React page looks like where I'm fetching and displaying.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Blog extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
    
        this.state = {
          blogPost: [],
          finishedLoading: true
        }
      }    
    
    async componentDidMount() {    
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/blogPosts/all')
        const json = await response.json()
        this.setState({ blogPost: json.blogPosts, finishedLoading: false })
      }
    
    reload = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/blogPosts/all')
        const json = await response.json()
        this.setState({ blogPost: json.blogPosts, finishedLoading: true })
      }
    
    render() {
        
    if (this.state.blogPost.length === 0) {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <h1>No blogposts have been posted!</h1>
          </div>
        )
    }
   

    return (
            <div class="blogPost">
                <h2>{this.state.blogPost.title}</h2>
                <p> Author: {this.state.blogPost.author}</p>
                <p>{this.state.blogPost.content}</p>
                <p>Comments:</p>

                <ul>
                
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Blog
```

Comment: What's the question???

Comment: @RuanDuarte Question's clear... There's a huge mistake in the author's side, which is common with new developers.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to check the answer, but there was a certain amount of time that had to pass before I could do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to iterate through the contents but you're doing only once, that too on an array:

```
return (
  <div class="blogPost">
    <h2>{this.state.blogPost.title}</h2>
    <p> Author: {this.state.blogPost.author}</p>
    <p>{this.state.blogPost.content}</p>
    <p>Comments:</p>

    <ul></ul>
  </div>
);
```

The above code is wrong. What you need to do is **iterate the contents of `this.state.blogPost`, which is an array of `blog` objects**:

```
return this.state.blogPost.map((blog, key) => (
  <div class="blogPost" key={key}>
    <h2>{blog.title}</h2>
    <p> Author: {blog.author}</p>
    <p>{blog.content}</p>
    <p>Comments:</p>
    <ul></ul>
  </div>
));
```

You might need to do the same thing to fetch the comments too. Say, the comments are an array of `comments` in the object, then do this:

```
return this.state.blogPost.map((blog, key) => (
  <div class="blogPost" key={key}>
    <h2>{blog.title}</h2>
    <p> Author: {blog.author}</p>
    <p>{blog.content}</p>
    <p>Comments:</p>
    <ul>
      {blog.comments.length > 0 ? (
        blog.comments.map((c, k) => <li key={key}>{c}</li>)
      ) : (
        <li>No comments.</li>
      )}
    </ul>
  </div>
));
```

---

**Full code here:**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Blog extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      blogPost: [],
      finishedLoading: true
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/blogPosts/all");
    const json = await response.json();
    this.setState({ blogPost: json.blogPosts, finishedLoading: false });
  }

  reload = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/blogPosts/all");
    const json = await response.json();
    this.setState({ blogPost: json.blogPosts, finishedLoading: true });
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.blogPost.length === 0) {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>No blogposts have been posted!</h1>
        </div>
      );
    }

    return this.state.blogPost.map((blog, key) => (
      <div class="blogPost" key={key}>
        <h2>{blog.title}</h2>
        <p> Author: {blog.author}</p>
        <p>{blog.content}</p>
        <p>Comments:</p>
        <ul>
          {blog.comments.length > 0 ? (
            blog.comments.map((c, k) => <li key={key}>{c}</li>)
          ) : (
            <li>No comments.</li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    ));
  }
}

export default Blog;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `this.state.blogPost` to an array of blogPosts that you receive from your database. So, `this.state.blogPost.author` will be undefined since an array won't have a `.author` property. The items inside the array will have the property instead, accessed like so: `this.state.blogPost[0].author` to get the author of the first post.

To display a `div` for every item in the array, you need to loop through the array in your render function with `.map`:

```
return (
        this.state.blogPost.map((post, index) => (
            <div class="blogPost" key={index}>
                <h2>{post.title}</h2>
                <p> Author: {post.author}</p>
                <p>{post.content}</p>
                <p>Comments:</p>
                
                <ul>
                
                </ul>
            </div>
        ));
        
    )
```

**Edit:** looks like I was beat to the punch!

Comment: _looks like I was beat to the punch!_ - What does this mean? 

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman it means you were fast and answered the question before I could, it's nothing bad

Comment: Yea, I know it was a friendly thing! Haha. Just wanted to know the context.  Wait, did you not see the emoji? This one - ""